# Capybara webkit 1.7 & qt5 - Rails page caching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt, capybara, capybara-webkit

I upgraded my test gems to the following versions:

`capybara` **2.5.0**

`capybara-webkit` **1.7.1**

I installed `qt5` and the `capybara-webkit` gem successfully.

I test my application with cucumber. In a scenario outline that checks some field values, the first example passes but all subsequent examples fail.

After digging into the logs, I found that in every example except the first one, Rails responds with status **304 Not Modified** instead of **200 OK** which was the previous behaviour.

I monkey patched my application controller for the test environment to respond with headers disabling the cache and all works as expected. But this was just a fix to confirm that page caching was the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth No, for the moment I downgraded to qt4...